# Force of weight vs Force of gravity on an object in equilibirum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

Hi,
In the picture above, the person is in equilibrium. I know that the tensions of the strings are pulling her up. But for the force that is pulling her down, would I say it is the force of gravity or the force of her weight. I know that gravity causes weights, so would I say it is the force of gravity that is pushing her down?

Thanks

Comment: *would I say it is the force of gravity or the force of her weight.* The force of gravity, i.e. mass $\times$ gravitational acceleration, **IS** the weight: $W=mg$. That's what the term "*weight*" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Gert says in comments, **weight** is just another name for **gravitational force**.

You might hear about this formula for weight:

$$w=mg$$

and this formula for gravitational force:

$$F_g=G \frac{Mm}{r^2}$$

as if those are two different forces. But in fact, the lowercase $g$ is just a name for a chunk of the parameters: $g=G\frac{M}{r^2}$. So the two formulas are the very same thing:

$$F_g=G \frac{Mm}{r^2}=m\,\underbrace{\left(G \frac{M}{r^2}\right)}_g=mg=w$$

because the two forces are the very same thing.

**Note**: Even though *weight* and *gravitational force* are two words for the same thing, we often like to use them in different scenarios. When saying *weight* we usually mean the gravitational force on a very tiny object by a very large object (like a stone and a planet). We usually wouldn't say *weight* about the Moon, though, although it would technically be correct.